# How to retrieve only spreadsheet title from google sheets v4 api

Tags: google-sheets-api

I am looking for an example of how to retrieve only the title of the spreadsheet for a given spreadsheetId using GET and no client library.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

fields=properties/title

E.g. https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/[spreadsheetId]?fields=properties%2Ftitle